Recursively defined sequence - Convergence and boundedness
I’m stuck on the following task and need your help.
Namely, a recursively defined sequence is defined by: \begin{equation}
x_0 = 2, \quad x_{n+1} = -x_n + (-1)^{n} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}
\end{equation} I am now supposed to show that this sequence does not converge, but has exactly one limit superior and limit inferior.
Generally and without proof: By explicitly calculating the first 5 sequence elements, I suspect that the even sequence elements converge to 1 and the odd sequence elements converge to - 1. These are then also the sequence - accumulation points and thus LimSup and LimInf. Since there are two APs, the sequence cannot be convergent. The sequence thus approaches 1 and - 1 in an oscillating manner.
For non - convergence: I think this could be shown by proving that \begin{equation}
x_n
\end{equation}is not a Cauchy - sequence. First, I tried to show the non - convergence by proving that the even and odd subsequences  converge to different limit values. The recursivity makes everything very difficult. Do you think the approach via Cauchy - sequences makes more sense?
Limit Superior and Limit Inferior: I think to show that these exist I have to prove that the sequence is bounded. Then the theorem of Weierstraß applies and there exists a largest and smallest sequence - accumulation point. I tried it with induction but failed.
Can you help ?
Thank you for your help!

Does this answer your question? Recursive geometric series to explicit formula or this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673996

I would first consider the simpler problem $x_{n+1}=-x_{n}.$.

Hint: define $y_n=x_{2n}$. Now what can you prove about $y_n$? What if $y_n=x_{2n-1}$ instead?

Define your even subsequence by
$$y_n=x_{2n}=-x_{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2^{2n}}=x_{2n-2}-\frac{1}{2^{2n}}-\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}=y_{n-1}-\frac{3}{4^n}$$
This sequence is Cauchy since ($n\geq m$)
$$|y_n-y_m|=|\frac{1}{4^m}+\frac{1}{4^{m+1}}+...+\frac{1}{4^{n}}|<\sum_{k=m}^\infty \frac{3}{4^k}= \frac{1}{4^{m-1}}$$
which goes to $0$ as $m$ increases. A similar argument can be made for the odd subsequence (ie it converges). $y_n$ can also be used to show that $x_n$ does not converge. Let $y_n\to y$ and note that $y_1=\frac{5}{4}$. Then for large enough $n$ we have
$$y>y_n-\frac{1}{8}=y_{n-1}-\frac{1}{4^n}-\frac{1}{8}=...=y_1-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{3}{4^k}-\frac{1}{8}$$
$$>y_1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{3}{4^k}-\frac{1}{8}=\frac{5}{4}-1-\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{8}>0$$
Now, assume that $x_n$ converges. That is
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[-x_{n-1}+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right]=-\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n-1}=-L$$
which implies $L=-L$ or $L=0$. But this is impossible since $x_{2n}$ is eventually greater than $\frac{1}{8}$. We conclude $x_n$ does not converge but has exactly two limit points.
